# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library oracle 10

Tags: python

Iam trying to connect to 10g oracle using python it is showing this error
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library
Iam using win7

Comment: You should review the installation instructions for Oracle DB. This does not appear to be a Python issue per se

Comment: Those installation instructions are at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows.  You will need to make sure cx_Oracle is linking with an older Instant Client e.g. 11.2 and not with the libraries in your 10g database.  You can do this by fiddling with your PATH setting before you run Python.